# Which Cassandra PHP Client supports CompositeTypes and Comparators?

Tags: php, cassandra

I am looking for a PHP Client for Cassandra that supports CompositeType and also creation and modification of ColumnFamilies/Keyspace (schema). Haven't found any that support CompositeType.

Please help. Any workaround to circumvent this issue?

Thank you.

**Update:**

As suggested by **Tamil** I am using the following statement to create the column family in **cassandra-cli**.

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY User
with comparator = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type)'
and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';
```

Now using pycassa I am using the following update statement to insert row.

```
UPDATE User set
'meta:fullname:none' = 'Praveen Baratam'
where
KEY = 'praveen';

UPDATE User set
'meta:using:none' = 'cassandra'
where
KEY = 'praveen';

UPDATE User set
'meta:location:none' = 'India'
where
KEY = 'praveen';
```

Subsequently I am doing a range-slice query using the following statements.

```
SELECT 'meta'..'zeta' from User where KEY = 'praveen';

SELECT 'meta:a'..'meta:z' from User where KEY = 'praveen';
```

Thanks a lot to Tamil for this work-around till CQL supports CompositeType in Cassandra 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Praveen, You can use phpcassa & cql to work around with composite types. Although either phpcassa or cql doesn't support composite types it works for me.

Ex:

```
$servers = array('127.0.0.1:9160');
$pool = new ConnectionPool("Stats",$servers);
$raw = $pool->get();
$rows = $raw->client->execute_cql_query("SELECT 'a:b' from TestColumnFamily WHERE KEY='xxx:1'", cassandra_Compression::NONE);
```

But you have to sanitize the content returned because this might hexstring.

Check out [this](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com/search/label/cql) if you have problems using phpcassa cql

The above answer is outdated PHPCassa 1.0.a.1 has a full support for composites check out this [blog post](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.in/2012/03/cassandra-phpcassa-composite-types.html)

Comment: Hello Tamil, Thanks a lot for the tip. It would be great if you can specify example for CRUD operations using compositeType. I am completely lost regarding how to insert/update data using CQl into CF with CompositeType. I am currently looking into pdo_cassandra as client library. My CF schema is - create column family User
    with comparator = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type)'
    and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
    and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';

Comment: $raw->client->execute_cql_query("UPDATE TestColumnFamily set 'a:b'='a:b'+1, 'c:d'='c:d'+1 where key='test'", cassandra_Compression::NONE); This is how I update counters with composite type as comparators. Hope the same works for ordinary column families

Comment: How about doing range slices with compositeColumns? Can you give an example? I am trying to use the raw Thrift PHP API. After all this tussle, the basic API looks easier! Unless you check if range slices are working as expected, you cannot actually make sure that you are using concatenated-strings or CompositeColumns I guess. Did you validate using CQLSH?

Comment: @Praveen everything works fine for me. I tested it by listing all columns of a row after insertions and found that integrity and sorting remains as expected. I do slice queries on columns via select 'a'..'z' from TestColumnFamily where key='test'. This works for me. One more thing cql doesn't support composite type though. So  I can't use cqlsh to validate point queries but column slicing works.

Comment: Thank you Tamil. You rock. :-)